# Firebase Cloud Functions Firestore - Cannot read property 'text' of null

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to write a Google cloud function that reads from document.

**This function is working fine, it can return value:**

```
exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    var userArr = [];
    fs.collection("user")
        .where("user_id", "==", "qIXpbXTuJ5PQHm3rGuTeeSbdnWi1")
        .get()
        .then(querySnapshot => {
            querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
                userArr.push(doc.data());
            });
            response.send(userArr);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            return err;
        });
});
```

**But this one return error:**

Server

```
exports.matches_people = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    var userArr = [];
    fs.collection("user")
        .where("user_id", "==", "qIXpbXTuJ5PQHm3rGuTeeSbdnWi1")
        .get()
        .then(querySnapshot => {
            querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
                userArr.push(doc.data());
            });
            return userArr;
        })
        .catch(err => {
            return err;
        });
});
```

Client

```
var matches_people = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('matches_people');
                matches_people({
                    user_id:  self.login.user_id
                }).then(function (result) {
                    // Read result of the Cloud Function.
                    var sanitizedMessage = result.data.text;
                    console.log(result);
                    // ...
                }).catch(function (error) {
                    // Getting the Error details.
                    var code = error.code;
                    var message = error.message;
                    var details = error.details;
                    console.log(error); //return error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of null
                    // ...
                });
```

On httpsCallable, it return error
[TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14aAa.png)

Please help.

Sorry for my English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTTP Callable Functions, in order to "return data after an asynchronous operation, **return a promise**", as explained in the doc [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable).

The `get()` method is asynchronous and returns a promise, as explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query#get).

So you should just return the promise returned by the `get()` method, as follows:

```
exports.matches_people = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    var userArr = [];
    return fs.collection("user")   //  <- Note the return here
        .where("user_id", "==", "qIXpbXTuJ5PQHm3rGuTeeSbdnWi1")
        .get()
        .then(querySnapshot => {
            querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
                userArr.push(doc.data());
            });
            return userArr;
        })
        .catch(err => {
            return err;
        });
});
```

Note that this is different for HTTP Cloud Functions, that you shall end with `send()`, `redirect()` or `end()`.